# Changing a positive value to a negative one

Tags: android

In Android how can I change a value to a negative number?

If I have the following code and have entered 10 for `pos1_deg`, how can I easily change this to -10 using a radio button?
Is the answer to concatenate a string such as `pos1_deg = "-" + pos1_deg`? Or is there some mathematical command I can use?

```
pos1_deg =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.sat1posdeg);
pos1_deg.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiply `pos1_deg` by `-1`:

```
pos1_deg * -1
```

Answer (score 14):

As the others suggested you can use that way to convert a positive to a negative but what if you have a negative instead of a positive(i don't know your requirement) so better use :

Math.abs(pos1_deg) and use any of above techniques e.g

```
Math.abs(po1_deg) * -1
0 - Math.abs(pos1_deg)
```

so you won't get any error calculations...

Answer (score 5):

Just subtract from zero to invert the sign.

```
0 - pos1_deg
```

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but this is far less readable to me than pos1_deg * -1. Just a matter of taste though.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress1,

        boolean fromUser)
{
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        value2.setText("Right Contact:"+B);
        value3.setText("Delta:"+(A-B));
        B = -1*progress1 ;

}
```

answer

Answer (score 0):

from api 24 you can use

> Math.negateExact(pos1_deg)

pos1_deg is your int